# Stop rounding from Xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlsx, xlsxwriter

when i have a calculated number for example : 1112121.43
After writing to excel from python : sheet.write()
The number being displayed on excel with a rounding :   1112121.40
by removing the '3' i tried to add a number format to the workbook, and tried to increase the zeroes after the . but nothing worked.

```
number_formatter = workbook.add_format({'num_format':'#,##0.00})
sheet.write(row_numb,column_numb, amount, number_formatter)
```

output in excel : 1,112,121.**40**
expected output : 1,112,121.**43**

Comment: Please create a [reprex].

Comment: can you check now please

Answer (score 0):

You can get rounding in Excel, or Python, or anywhere else that uses floating point numbers but it shouldn't happen for a number that small or with that few decimal places.

Here is an example that shows that it is written without rounding:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Make the column wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 12)


# Unformatted number.
worksheet.write(0, 0, 1112121.43)

# Formatted number.
number_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "#,##0.00"})
worksheet.write(1, 0, 1112121.43, number_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Excel (and XlsxWriter) uses [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) floats which have a precision of  around 15 digits.

Comment: it's not working for me.

Comment: Then you will need to add a small complete working example that demonstrates that it doesn’t work.

Comment: it's not feasible by excel, numbers above 15 digits will automatically be replaced by zeroes.

Comment: Correct. But the number you show has only 9 digits and that can be stored by Excel to the required precision. So if you number is being rounded it isn’t being rounded by XlsxWriter or Excel (for the case you’ve shown).